# Annoying box next to the letter

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

Ηow can I get rid of this annoying box next to the letter as well the full stop

**update-1:** but to keep the Greek alphabet to the second level
[image]

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi})}    


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item text

  \begin{enumerate}
   \item text
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could specify the labels for the second level list as `begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*]`, or use `enumitem`'s `\setlist` feature, which would be preferrable.

Comment: what I want is to be applied universally, because the text is already been written and is difficult to change all the `begin{enumerate}`. With that you propose lost and the brackets... :)

Comment: \setlist[enumerate]{label=\roman*}, please see the enumitem manual. In the manual you will also find how to specify what to do on the various nested levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The annoying box is because Greek numerals should be followed by the character that `xgreek` calls `\anwtonos`, U+0374 (GREEK NUMERAL SIGN) that's apparently missing in Arial.

You can get redefine `\anwtonos` to everything you want, even to nothing:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\roman*)}

\renewcommand{\anwtonos}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item text

  \begin{enumerate}
   \item text
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The example uses Old Standard because it's one where U+0374 is present. Use whatever font with Greek characters you prefer.

[image]

Comment: works perfectly ... :)

Answer (score 2):

The "box" means that you are using a char which is not in the font. xgreek prints after the alpha the Unicode Character 'GREEK NUMERAL SIGN' (U+0374) but it is not in Arial.

You should either switch to another font (e.g. Arial Unicode MS) or redefine `\greeknumeral`, or `\anwtonos`